# Processing an array that can't be kept in memory

Tags: java, arrays, memory

I have to process a big array of string in Java, which can't be kept in memory. Because of this, the array must be processed in several chunks. The size of each chunk can be specified by the program's user, but if the user doesn't specify a size, the program must decide the most appropriate size.

My first thought was to use a in-disk database like cassandra. That way, every time I want to process a chunk of the big array, I would do a query to the database.
The problem I saw was that I'd need to control available memory of the JVM and RAM, which I think would be too difficult. Also, I would have to figure out how to set the size of each chunk to make the most of the available memory without filling it.

For that, I've thought about using something like MemCached or SSDB (alternative to Redis that allows you to store a part of the database in disk - https://github.com/ideawu/ssdb), but I'm not sure if that's the best option. The idea is that Memcached or SSDB would help manage the exchange of data between memory and disk without me having to implement any control to avoid filling memory.

Really, I don't like too much the idea of adding dependencies (Memcached or SSDB) just to make my program function.

Then, my question is: are there any good alternatives to solve my problem? Is the previous reasoning wrong?

Thanks in advance!

**CLARIFICATIONS
---------------**

**What kind of processing do you have to do?**
processing is related to data analysis techniques for getting information using existing data (in the big array)

**How big is the array? How big are the strings? Is your processing random access or sequential? Why can't you just use a file?**
the size of the array can change, it haven't a fixed value. The idea is that a user (not end-user) can processing an array in chunk when it's neccesary for him. For example, an user maybe want to process an array of size 100.000 in several chunk and other user don't need to process an array in several chunk while the size of the array is less than 1.000.000 (depending on the size of memory of each user).
My processing is sequential.
I don't use a file because in other questions of this page recommend that it's better to use a database rather than a file. Moreover, if I used a file, I have to control the available memory space, preventing the memory is full (and an error occurs in the program)

**Where are the Strings you wanna process? Are they already stored somewhere, or do you generate them somehow on the fly?**
Strings are obtained from users and they were stored in an array completely. Now, the idea is to store the strings passed by the user to the database, and later (when user decide), the processing of strings will be done (it haven't to be immediately after storing the strings in the database).

Comment: What kind of processing do you have to do?

Comment: How big is the array? How big are the strings? Is your processing random access or sequential? Why can't you just use a file?

Comment: Where are the Strings you wanna process? Are they already stored somewhere, or do you generate them somehow on the fly?

Comment: I added some clarification to your questions. Thanks!!

Comment: Why not a [memory mapped file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file)?

Comment: the problem I see is that you have to implement the control of memory, preventing that the memory is full (but an error occurs in the program and finishes its execution). Using memcached or ssdb, the control of the memory is performed (when the memory is full o reaches the limit set, and you want to load other data from disk to memory, MEMCACHED o ssdb do that internally - so you haven't to worry about doing that). I think to implement this control of memory can be too hard! Do you agree? or am I wrong?

Comment: You have not at all well described the type of processing you do.  If it is indeed sequential, you should be able to process in more or less standard disk buffers, with no real need to be concerned about "chunk size" or running out of heap.  I suspect you're making it too complicated.